# Task 'Xmx512m' not found in root project

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle, jvm-arguments

Task 'Xmx512m' not found in root project 'MyProject'

in *gradle.properties* it's showing Xmx1024m.

How can i get rid off this gradle build error?
My OS is windows 10.

build.gradle Module

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "in.ravisir.mateinstitute"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 24
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
          minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:10.0.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

build.gradle Myapplication

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your relevant Gradle files

Comment: @VadimKotov look into codes

Comment: Please [edit] your question, not post your code as an answer

Comment: @VadimKotov Sir, look into it now plzz